# Xenix / SCO V running in contemporary machines as VMs

Tags: osx, virtual-machine, sco, vmware-fusion

I am trying to install Xenix 386 and/or SCO V Unix in a VM for historical/research/reviving old times/curiosity purposes.

I have already tried to download a couple of media installation images from [here](https://winworldpc.com/product/xenix/sysv-386-v3x).

Tried to boot them several time to install the OS, still without much success; up until now

I already tried with VmWare fusion in OS/X:

- selecting a 32-bit VM
- disabling sound cards and USB, to limit the potential interfence of unknown hardware to those OSes
- giving it just a couple megabytes of RAM
- Limiting the virtual disk to the known limit of < 250MB
- testing IDE and SCSI disk emulation.

Both in Xenix and SCO V, the installation diskette (N1) seems to boot, however either the hard disk is not recognised, or the installation hangs with the message:

"Setting up disk environment"

What to do?

Comment: I think this question may fit [retrocomputing.stackexchange.com](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) a bit better.

Comment: @dirkt Not sure indeed. My main worry here is running it in contemporary computing resources, and not emulating anything.

Comment: I have found a copy of the OS https://archiveos.org/xenix/
How did you get this to run in Hyper-V?

Comment: @JonathanLee I have seen your later post with a successful setup and complete disk set link . Per the comment on the above link, it is (indeed) missing N1, the boot disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a very interested of couple of articles about a bug, [post1](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/the-xenix-386-2-2-3-mystery/) and [post2](https://soylentnews.org/article.pl?sid=17/03/03/1620222) in the installation/disk driver that explained why it did not run in many hardware platforms over the years.

The link, besides explaining the bug, also points out VirtualBox seems to emulate the behaviour and is able to boot those operating systems.

So I installed Virtualbox.

While it did not recognise an emulated SCSI disk, it recognised an emulated IDE disk < 250MB and got indeed into the installation phase.

```
Setting up installation environment...
%disk     0x1F0-01F7 14         -        type=W0 unit=0 cyls=734 hds=16 secs=31

Welcome to the SCO Unix installation.

Installation media used will be Compact Disc (CD-ROM)

Hit return to continue
```

> ...so I grabbed QEMU, and popped N1 in and booted it up. Unfortunately,
>   the system would hang almost immediately after. Some testing revealed
>   that the same issue existed on Bochs. PCjs got a bit further, but
>   kernel panicked nearly immediately. Somewhat surprising to me though
>   was VirtualBox not only booted, it got to the first step of the
>   installer.
>
> The OS is extremely picky about the hardware and BIOS and won’t boot
>   at all in many virtualizers. It also contains an interesting bug in
>   the AT disk driver (called ‘wd1010’ in this XENIX kernel version)
>   which causes the system to hang if the controller, or more likely an
>   IDE disk, responds “too fast” to the Set Drive Parameters command.

P.S. There seems to be hints people managed to hack/patch the bug out. There is no documentation about that, and the process should be specific to the hacked versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this but I have successfully virtualised SCO 5.0.6 using libvirt and it runs in production for a small business client (20 telnet users).

IDE disk, pcnet NIC, 1 x kvm64 CPU, 256 MB RAM

I did type up a p2v document if you're still interested.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you describe the process or post a link?

Comment: [http://www.writeurl.com/text/rgsxy1cxxxrk2q2gds70/jlgaa5bdirm637d298t2](http://www.writeurl.com/text/rgsxy1cxxxrk2q2gds70/jlgaa5bdirm637d298t2)

Looks like it was 5.0.5, but what's 0.0.1 between friends?

Comment: I am afraid the link is not working anymore. was it temporary?

Answer (score -1):

**PART1**

Check out this URL link below it has a guide to get this Microsoft Xenix fully running, plus it works. I just tested it out and I got Xenix running with it. This guide has directions for running a Xenix box inside of Virtualbox. So excited, I just tested the command bc and was doing calculations!!!

[image: Xenix Running]

Ref:
https://www.linux.org/threads/xenix-on-linux.11207/

Screenshot of Link to Xenix software and applications
[image: package locations]
REf:
https://archive.org/download/Xenix386Ports

[image: Standard]
Choose standard disk

Overwrite choose yes

choose q to continue
[image: options]
just use full disk for Xenix partitioning. option 2 after hit enter to confirm. Next two options choose q you do not need to run a bad sector scan for the virtual drive.
[image: defaults]
After use default of 15
select n for the next two options after enter your serial number.
[image: serial]
Use your provided serial from the .txt file from the archive website.

Comment: Can you post a summary of the relevant points here? Otherwise when the link target dies your answer becomes worthless

Comment: done, I will reply again because I cannot post more than 8 photos a time right now.

Answer (score -1):

**PART2**

after you enter your serial number reboot without the image in the flex drive.
[image: prompts]
The software will prompt you for the rest of the disks. Starting with B1, once the disk is loaded virtually into the flex floppy disk controller, enter your root password you want set. Hard set your timezone and continue your installation.
[image]
option 2
option 1 needed it will ask for X1 disk insert that.
[image: option 1]
use option 1
[image: all]
type ALL
follow requests for disks.
[image]
when prompted only root filesystem choose yes. Set another password. Set another password go back to N1 and N2 enter the serial number again provided in the zip file for a second time to hard set it to the drive.

Now remove disks from drive and reboot from HDD.

do CTL D when it asks, hit enter to confirm timezone.
Now log in as root insert your TCP/IP disks, type custom on the root terminal and install this as 3rd party.

I hope that helps. Roaima requested I post a summary of this. Here you go.

[image: root]
Use command **"custom"** to install 3rd party software like TCP/IP streams.
[image: custom use]
choose option 1 and type RUNTIME
[image: TCP]
TCP stack install use serial listed on main site.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that since this is not a forum, the order of posts in the answer section is subject to user preferences and not guaranteed. As such, an answer should not be split across multiple posts.

Comment: I cannot have 8 links currently, to add the screenshots. sorry about that.

Answer (score -2):

**Part 3 Optional:**

type **Custom**
Now you can Install TCP steams first with serial number,
after that quit and run custom again.

type **Custom** and install TCP 1,2,3

type **Custom** and install TCP maintain disk
[image: tcp running]
**(Image: TCP stack running and pinging loopback)**

Command CUSTOM will allow for 3rd party software.

use command **mkdev 3com** follow prompts

next use command **mkdev tcp** follow prompts

next set route add default gateway.

Example: **route add 192.168.1.1 1** this will create a default route.

Xenix with the supported TCP stack, I have the ifconfig command now.

I am so thankful for this older software I love this stuff.

All the iso files are for the floppy/flex drive controller.

**Side Notes:**
I am still working on getting Xenix to ping my router it will not work still. However, this can ping the loopback now that is a big step in the direction of lynx use.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that since this is not a forum, the order of posts in the answer section is subject to user preferences and not guaranteed. As such, an answer should not be split across multiple posts.

Comment: sorry I was not able to get this into one post it has over 8 photos.

Comment: What is recommended for posts with large number of screenshots, it is currently blocking me at over 8. I had this originally as one post and it would not let me continue.